# Creating & View IndoorOSM or IndoorGML files

Tags: android, openstreetmap, indoor-positioning-system, gml-geographic-markup-lan

I am working on a **indoor navigation** project with Googles Project Tango tablet (Android). I can scan a building with it an created a internal graph representation of the floorplan (map). I want to **convert my graph** either to the [IndoorOSM](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/IndoorOSM) or the [Indoor GML](http://indoorgml.net/) format. This will be a bit complicated.

But to check if the conversion is successfull, I am looking for a **viewer** for one of this formats, but didn't found anything working. Can anyone help me or recommend me another format? I am a beginner in XML, GIS, etc. I posted this question also on [help.openstreetmap.org](https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/49923/creating-view-indoorosm-files).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm developing a viewer for IndoorGML format and It is based on WebGL.
This tool is just simple version now, but I think you may use it well on your purpose.

In this time we are focusing on viewing indoor map with 3D Space which has solid geometry, so importing indoor map with 2D Space which has polygon geometry is not supported yet. 
But we are supposed to add it very soon.

Following is the URL.
https://github.com/STEMLab/IndoorGML-Viewer

If you have any question, please don't hesitate.

Regards,
Hyung-Gyu Ryoo.

Comment: Thank you. I saw in your github that you have also developed a JOSM-Indoor Editor. So would you recommend me the IndoorGML or the IndoorOSM format? Which one is the simplest to convert from my graph? I have hallways (nodes) with rooms and markers in it and hallways are connected with entrypoints (edges). I store the edge points of a hallway and the positions of rooms, markers and entrypoints. All coordinates are 2D/3D in respect to the start of the session.

Comment: I recommend IndoorGML format. as far as I know, there is no graph structure of indoor space in order to support indoor routing in IndoorOSM. on the other hand, in IndoorGML, you can represent the indoor graph with SpaceLayer structure which has State and Transition similar with node and edge. It's possible to represent the space too.